# When people get over their fears, do they get over it, or do they just get used to it?

Tags: fear

When people fear something, and then at a later time don't, have they just gotten used to the feeling of fear, or are they actually less scared? If it varies by which fear we are talking about, then for the fear of darkness specifically and also for all other fears.

I was discussing it with a friend today, and they said, that people just get used to their fears, but it doesn't seem to make sense, and they couldn't explain to me why that would be the case.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Other than discussing it with a friend, have you done any research by searching the internet or similar? If so what did you find?

Comment: I tried searching it on google with various keywords, but all I get is tutorials on how to overcome fear. If you have any ideas on what to search, that would be greatly appreciated.